# Trouble understanding why this OCaml snippet won't compile

Tags: compiler-errors, reference, ocaml

I'm new to OCaml and functional programming in general, and I'm struggling with the syntax. I find it difficult to write programs, since it seems to me that I'll write what I understand to be essentially the same code, but on the one hand one snippet compiles and runs with no issue but the other doesn't.

Here's one such case:

```
let foo () = 
     let x = ref 0 in !x
;;

val foo : unit -> int = <fun>
```

Compiles without a problem. My understanding of the above snippet is that when we call `foo`, we bind `x` to a reference to a memory cell storing 0, and then dereference `x`.

Now this snippet:

```
let seed = ref 6;;

let show_ref () = 
  let seed:=!seed+1 in !seed
;;
```

won't compile, and I don't understand why. It seems to me we do essentially the same thing here; we create a binding `seed` to a reference to memory cell containing the value `6`. Then, we create a function that increments the thing stored in the cell referenced by `seed`, and then we dereference `seed`.

It's probably because I'm missing something basic, but I don't understand why the first thing was fine and the other was not fine. Could someone help me figure out what's really going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an OCaml language construct:

```
let name = expression1 in expression2
```

There is no OCaml language construct:

```
let name := expression1 in expression2
```

One way to look at this is that `=` is not an operator in the first case. It's just part of the syntax of `let`. This means you can't replace it by an arbitrary other operator as you are trying to do.

For completeness, here's how to write your second function:

```
let show_ref () =
    seed := !seed + 1;
    !seed
```

Note that in this code `=` is not an operator. But `!`, `:=`, and `+` are operators. You could define other symbols for these three operations (though you need to be careful of precedence). But you can't define a different symbol to use instead of `=` in a `let` expression.

Comment: @Jeffery Scofield Thanks for the answer, I understand the issue now--but what does the lone semicolon do?

Comment: Good question. A semicolon is like an operator (but can't be redefined). It takes an expression on each side. It discards the value of the expression at the left (which should conventionally have type `unit`) and returns the value of the expression on the right.

Comment: I would add that `a (); b ()` ensures that `a ()` is computed before `b ()`. This is not the case if you do `f (a ()) (b ())` or `a () + b ()`, for which the order of evaluation of `a ()` and `b ()` is unspecified - it can be right-to-left or left-to-right.

Comment: Absolutely. I would have added that myself if I could edit my comment.

Comment: I think there may be a common misunderstanding here coming from many other programming languages. In many other languages, assigning a value to a variable also returns the variable or its value, so we can do things like `while (*a = some_function()) { ... }"`.  Not so in OCaml with the `:=` operator. _But_ `:=` is just a function: `let (:=) r v = r.contents <- v`. There's nothing stopping a programmer from defining their own function for this that to some level replicates the behavior they're used to. `let (<<=) r v = r.contents <- v; r` or even `let (<<!) r v = r <<= v |> (!)`.